# Link Length and Strength from attribute

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

It is possible to have a different link strength or length attribute for each link in a force based layout?

Below is an example dataset where the length and strength of each link would be defined as an attribute

```
        var dataset = {
            nodes: [
                { name: "Adam" },
                { name: "Iris" },
                { name: "Jerry" }
            ],
            edges: [
                { source: 0, target: 1, strength : .1, length: 50 },
                { source: 0, target: 2, strength: 1, length: 100 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`force.linkStrength` accepts a function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#linkStrength). Likewise for linkDistance. You can even see [how it's implemented.](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/d3.js#L6340)

```
d3.layout.force()
  ...
  .links(dataset.edges)
  .linkStrength( function(edge, i) { return edge.strength; } )
```